# How much time it will take a B787 to fuel completely when empty?

Tags: fuel, boeing-787

When a big jet like B787 needs to be fueled with empty tanks, ideally how much time it will take to go full?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Boeing](http://www.boeing.com/assets/pdf/commercial/airports/acaps/7474sec5.pdf) (via [airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/335483/)), it takes 53 minutes to load 55,800 US gallons with two fuel trucks operating at 35 psi delivery pressure. The total fuel capacity of the 787-8 is 33,340 US gal, so fueling from empty to full should take about 31.6 minutes with two trucks.

Comment: That's a fantastic answer, but may I trouble you for a source?

Comment: @Lightsider here is the source : http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/335483/

Comment: 55800 US gallons is about 200 tons. How do you get that into 2 fuel trucks?

Comment: @steveverrill most large airports have hydrant system which feed fuel to trucks. The truck just pump the fuel from hydrant to plane.