# How much fuel aircraft should carry to complete flight plan?

Tags: flight-planning, fuel, flight-path

[Here is the question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15955/how-much-time-it-will-take-a-b787-to-fuel-completely-when-empty) I was looking for (it didn't answer my question though), but this is specific to Boeing 787.

Is there any regulation to carry certain amount (may be %) of fuel aircraft should carry when its flight plan is prepared?

Note: We had argument that aircraft should carry 150% of fuel of it's planned travel, then someone bought argument of hijacking planes and said that 15 to 30 minutes of extra travel time fuel they have to carry.

Comment: Note that there is not legal/regulatory upper limit, but carrying extra fuel has a cost.

Comment: carrying extra fuel has a cost, but safety of the flight is on priority, right?

Comment: By *extra*, I mean past the lower regulatory limit described by @dave and the question linked above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may vary elsewhere in the world but according to the [FAA FAR Sec. 121.639](http://rgl.faa.gov/REGULATORY_AND_GUIDANCE_LIBRARY/RGFAR.NSF/0/1cc5b5dad63e4806852566ef006dd813!OpenDocument)

> Fuel supply: All domestic operations.
>
> No person may dispatch or take off an airplane unless it has enough
> fuel--
>
> - (a) To fly to the airport to which it is dispatched;
> - (b) Thereafter, to fly to and land at the most distant alternate airport
>   (where required) for the airport to which dispatched; and
> - (c) Thereafter, to fly for 45 minutes at normal cruising fuel consumption
>   or, for certificate holders who are authorized to conduct day VFR
>   operations in their operations specifications and who are operating
>   nontransport category airplanes type certificated after December 31,
>   1964, to fly for 30 minutes at normal cruising fuel consumption for
>   day VFR operations.